# can anyone explain this command fully adb shell sendevent [device] [type] [code] [value]?

Tags: shell, adb

Can anyone explain the following command fully:

```
adb shell sendevent [device] [type] [code] [value]
```

I am trying to write a script for touch events using send event command.

Comment: FYI the values used are potentially device / build specific.

Comment: @Chris, only touchscreen device name is device specific. Touch event protocol and include/linux/input.h constants have not changed that much. But personally I do prefer `input tap` command over `sendevent`for touch emulation.

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply not true.  The numeric codes are **quite** different on my various devices.

Comment: @Chris, would you mind posting the list of your devices? I would be very interested to find out if there are any non-legacy (i.e. ics4.0+ kernel 3.0+) devices which do not support the event codes from my answer below. I have got a couple of dozen devices myself and all of them use the same event codes.

Comment: You forget that much of the installed base runs older versions.  I don't think they've even stopped selling GB in major markets yet.

Comment: @AlexP. Can "input tap" handle multiple swipe events to draw pattern and unlock.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit I believe the command there would be "input swipe". (multiple of them) Not sure if it works, but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to find out the name of the touchscreen device on your phone or tablet. You can use this command in `adb shell` session:

```
getevent -pl 2>&1 | sed -n '/^add/{h}/ABS_MT_TOUCH/{x;s/[^/]*//p}'
```

Let's say the input device name is `/dev/input/event0` and you want to emulate a quick tap at coordinates x=300, y=400:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 300
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 400
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 48 5
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 58 50
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

The long touch (let's say 1sec long) at the same coordinates would be:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 300
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 400
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 48 5
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 58 50
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
sleep 1
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

For the explanation what those commands mean and do exactly please read [Emulating touchscreen interaction with sendevent in Android](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html).

Comment: Hello, your answer helped a lot, I wonder if you know something about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73683955/how-to-translate-device-screen-position-to-sendevent-position

Answer (score 0):

Im using ZTE blade(1.gen) CyanagenMod 7. The screen resolution is 480x800 After some trial and error I figured out that in order to press coordinates 240x 725y I actually had to implement the script like this: 988 = 240x, 2768 = 725y

```
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 988
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 2768
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 48 5
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 58 50
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

I was previously recording the events with get event and values it was giving were correct I just did not know how to interpret them = ).