# adb sendevent not working

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to simulate a touch in an android device, the fastest way possible. 
I think the fastest is low level (sendevents). 
I tried with "shell input tap" but it is too slow.

To do this I did:

```
adb shell getevent
```

and I've copied the output of my touch event:

```
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 00000867
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 00000095
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 00000233
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 ffffffff
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
```

After that I did a simple python script to run send this sendevents.

```
def sendevent (device,event):
    command = "adb -s " + device + " shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 " + event
    print (command)
    os.popen(command)


def touch_position():
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0003 0039 00000867")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0003 0035 00000095")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0003 0036 00000233")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0001 014a 000000010")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0000 0000 00000000")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0003 0039 ffffffff")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0001 014a 00000000")
    sendevent("fbc690357d04","0000 0000 00000000")
```

It is now working as I cant see any touch! 
Can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17263093/1778421

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `getevent` to record the events, it will give the output in the hexadecimal notation, so you need to convert them to decimal values. In python you can use `int('string', 16)` to convert a string in hexadecimal to decimal.