# How to translate device screen position to sendevent position?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I know about the `input tap x y` shell command, however, I'm trying to understand how to
perform a click using the `sendevent` command. I been able to achieve it with the following command:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 X &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 Y &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
```

Where `X` and `Y` is the position that will be clicked, I'm testing it on the android emulator `BlueStacks 5` which the Display Resolution set to `1920x1080`.

The code is working and the click is fired, however, I couldn't understand how to convert the position where I want to be clicked to the `sendevent` XY position.

If I send using ADB:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 2000 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 2000 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
```

It clicks somewhere around x75 y75, how this calc is done? i mean screen xy -> sendevent xy?

---

### How to replicate:

- First enable BlueStacks 5 adb in the window: `Settings -> Advanced -> Android debug bridge`
- Open a cmd window and run `cd C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt` assuming BlueStacks where installed in the default path.

Execute the commands:

- `hd-adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:X` where X is the port shown in the window where you enabled the ADB.
- `hd-adb.exe -s 127.0.0.1:X shell`

Now we are on the shell, execute a new command: `getevent -p`
and search for:

```
... /dev/input/event5
  name:     "BlueStacks Virtual Touch"
```

On my emulator the input event for touch is `event5` on yours it can be different, replace it according.

Now you can simulate a click with the code below changing `XY` to the position where you want to be clicked:

```
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 X &&
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 Y &&
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0 &&
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0 &&
    sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the emulator screen position to the `sendevent` position.

`For example`, if you want to perform a click at `x200 y200`, using `sendevent` what the value needed?

How to calculate it?

Comment: I believe those x and y are absolute screen coordinates (so not just window coordinates, you have to include the toolbar, statusbar, and other decorations).

Comment: @GabeSechan do you think is possible to calculate/convert? i mean any kind of formula

Comment: view.getLocationOnScreen() will return the screen coordinates of the upper left corner of the view.  THen you can add in whatever offset you want.  These will be specific to whatever emulator settings/device settings you have, as density and decorations are not the same globally.

Comment: @GabeSechan when i run `view.getLocationOnScreen()` on shell nothing happens

Comment: It's not a shell command, its a function in the app.  There's no way to do it from the shell, because the idea of a View isn't something that goes beyond the app it's in.

Comment: You wrote that the screen resolution is 1920x1080 but you send screen coordinates of 2000, 2000. Is it a typo?

Comment: @TDG no, to click on x1900~ using the ADB on the emulator i need to send `sendevent` with a value higher than `30000` weird.

Comment: Indeed weired, did you try it with a physical device?

Comment: No i dont only with the emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the very precise instructions to reproduce:

I enabled
Settings -> Advanced -> Input debugging -> Show visual feedback for taps
and
Settings -> Advanced -> Input debugging -> Show pointer location for current touch data

when I hold down click, I can see: `X:` `Y:`

I collected these x coordinate points, my max `X:` is `1600.0` so my width is `1600.0`

```
(8000, 390.6)
(16000, 781.2)
(32000, 1562.5)
```

then Excel: `X Y (scatter)` chart, add trendline, click trendline and click big + sign -> Chart Elements -> Trendline : (tick that) and ▶, More Options... -> Trendline Options -> Display Equation on chart

, click on the formula, then Label Options -> Category: Number, Decimal Places: 10
`y = 0.0488294643x - 0.0500000000`

`1600 = 0.0488294643x - 0.0500000000`
`32768.1252075501 = X`

I round to `32768` because `32768` is a magic number, close to Int16's `32767`
edit: after Nathan's comment, it's 32767 (32768 doesn't even move the cursor)

so the formula is : (W: width, H: height)

```
32767*X/W
32767*Y/H
```

for your `(X=200, Y=200, W=1980, H=1080)`

```
32767*200/1920
32767*200/1080

3413.22916666667
6067.96296296296
```

I used this code to test: it doesn't do a tap, it holds down without releasing

```
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 57 0
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 3413.22916666667
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 6067.96296296296
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 48 5
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 58 50
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
```

[https://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html#:~:text=ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID%20(57)%20%2D%20ID,end%20of%20report](https://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html#:%7E:text=ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID%20(57)%20%2D%20ID,end%20of%20report)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand how you get these values `0.0488294643x - 0.0500000000`

Comment: I omitted a step by accident but : Excel: `+` -> Chart Elements -> Trendline : (tick that) and ▶, More Options... -> Trendline Options -> Display Equation on chart <br> basically it computes the line of best fit and it gives the slope, I could very well have done `((781.2 - 390.6) / (16000 - 8000))` to get the slope since the points are almost perfectly aligned, but I didn't know that

Comment: so that was just looking if there was a mathematical relationship between these points, it's `y = mx` ? or as Gabe said: "you have to include the toolbar, statusbar, and other decorations" : `y = mx + b` ? it's easier with a formula than to manually figure out by code the size of the window ? : I'm thinking of : <https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm>

Comment: The toolbar has a fixed height of 32px, it is not possible to click on it using `sendevent` because he's on a different window and this window is not related to the android/adb. I'm testing it, looks like the formula is really `32767*x/w` `32767*y/h` `32768` on `sendevent` doesn't even fire the click. Thank you, Doge!